# SQL Server Entity Framework GetAll() is too slow

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

My Entity Framework generic repository project using SQL Server is too slow. How can I improve my project?

These queries are getting data in 30 seconds. I have 1000 items in `Answers` table and 300 rows in the `Questions` table

```
  List<QuestionVM> questionList = questionServices.GetAll()
                                                  .Where(x => x.SubCategory_Id == id) 
                                                  .ToList();
  List<AnswerVM> answersList = answerServices.GetAll()
                                             .Where(x => x.SubCat_Id == id)
                                             .ToList();
```

And this is my `GetAll` function

```
public IEnumerable<QuestionVM> GetAll()
{
    var data = ProjectMapper.ConvertToVMList<IEnumerable<QuestionVM>>(_QuestionRepository.GetAll());
    return (IEnumerable<QuestionVM>)data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i improve my project?

One easy way is throw away your custom repository and use the DbContext directly.

You're returning all the rows from the database and filtering them on the client.  You need to filter the DbSet in your DbContext and then copy the data into your ViewModel.

Comment: No, it has never been the newest concept. It has always been a delusion of badly educated. You DO Use a reposiutory and you DO use unit of work - it is called DbContext. All implementations I have ever seen just have convoluted the concept in a way that was hard to work with. There is a place for generic contexts, but NOT when you already have that. with DbContext.

Comment: Only changed to posting id to GetAll() on service. Now everthing is normal. Thanks.